# How can I implement editable choice field in Django?

Tags: django

I want to make `category`, where I can add new category or edit existing category in admin page.

I just thinking about implementing this with Django `choice` field but have some problem finding exact solution.

Is there any good way to do this? or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/) as you say...

Official documentation says "Generally, **it’s best to define choices inside a model class**, and to define a suitably-named constant for each value"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly using the `django-autocomplete-light` package. [From their docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#creation-of-new-choices-in-the-autocomplete-form):

> **Creation of new choices in the autocomplete form**
>
> The view may provide an extra option when it can’t find any result matching the user input. That option would have the label Create "query", where query is the content of the input and corresponds to what the user typed in.
>
> This allows the user to create objects on the fly from within the AJAX widget. When the user selects that option, the autocomplete script will make a POST request to the view. It should create the object and return the pk, so the item will then be added just as if it already had a PK:

There is also a [live demo](http://dal-yourlabs.rhcloud.com/admin/select2_one_to_one/testmodel/add/) where they demonstrate that functionality within the admin interface.